# When using LinearStateQueryCriteria, How to get the output of the query sorted in order of modification

Tags: kotlin, corda

When using LinearStateQueryCriteria,

Supposing I have the following states all having the same linearId,

```
S4 (unconsumed) created at t4 
S3 (consumed)   created at t3
S2 (consumed)   created at t2
S1 (consumed)   created at t1
```

How do I retrieve the latest state that has StateStatus = CONSUMED? Is it possible to sort the result list by some timestamp ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try specifying the Sorting condition to the vaultQueryBy function like:

```
 val sortAttribute = SortAttribute.Standard(Sort.VaultStateAttribute.RECORDED_TIME)
    val criteria = QueryCriteria.VaultQueryCriteria(stateRefs = listOf(stateRefs.first(), stateRefs.last()))
  val results = rpcOps.vaultQueryBy<IOUState>(criteria, sorting = Sort(setOf(Sort.SortColumn(sortAttribute, Sort.Direction.ASC))))
```

Comment: This worked for me .. would like to know what's the difference between RECORDED_TIME and CONSUMED_TIME

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible by using status = Vault.StateStatus.CONSUMED and then specifying the sorting in queryBy

```
val queryService = VaultQueryService<YourModelStateClass>
val criteria = QueryCriteria.LinearStateQueryCriteria(status = Vault.StateStatus.CONSUMED)
queryService.queryBy(
            criteria = criteria,
            sorting = Sort(
              setOf(
                Sort.SortColumn(
                  SortAttribute.Custom(
                    YourModelStateSchema::class.java,
                    YourModelStateSchema::updatedDatetime.name), 
                  Sort.Direction.DESC
                )
              )
            )
          )
```